# Stationary point definition

Tags: calculus

I know the definition of stationary point for a differential and continuous function $f$ is the follow:

**Definition 1:** Let $S=S_1\times...\times S_p$ a no empty set. When $f: S→\mathbb{R}$ is a scalar function of $n≥1$ variables then a point $x∈dom(f)$, $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a stationary point of $f$ if $∇f(x)=0$, i.e., $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}=0,\;\forall i=1,..,p.$$

But, I found an other definition in a paper from SIAM. It is:

**Definition 2:** $x=(x_1,...,x_n)$ is a stationary point for  $f: S→\mathbb{R}$ if

$$x_i=\arg\min_{y_i\in\mathcal{S_i}}f(x_1,...,x_{i-1},y_i,x_{i+1},...,x_p)$$

for all $i=1,...,p.$

I think Definition 2 is a definition of a local minimum of $f$, but I am not sure.

Somebody could help me? Also, if somebody could give me some reference, it will help me.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "arg" ?

Comment: ${\arg\max}_{{x\in S}}f(x)=\{x\in S:\,f(x)=\max_{{y\in S}}f(y)\}.$